# Проблемы с регулярными выражениями в C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение `"\".+\""`. Оно должно искать все что в `""`. И оно работает, но съедает за собой всю строку перед ним. Пример: `"123456":replace("123456","1")`. В этом примере оно должно было взять `"123456"`, но захватывает вместе с ним всю строку перед ним. Я пробовал разные варианты подбора, но результат тот же.

Comment: Перед `"123456"` нет других символов

Comment: Вы не поняли. Он берет "123456":replace... но должен был взять "123456".

Comment: Приведите [mre], в строке `"123456":replace` `:replace` не находит https://regex101.com/r/dHwPNh/1/

Comment: `\"[^\"]+\"` https://regex101.com/r/TYMO1C/1

Comment: @aepot а, так это всё строка, а не код. Если так, дал ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте ленивый поиск:

```
\".+?\"
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/TYMO1C/2

> **"123456"**:replace(**"123456"**,**"1"**)